# How to punctuate "To be, or not to be, that is the question"

Tags: punctuation, shakespeare

What would be the correct way to punctuate this line from Hamlet?

Should there simply be commas or should a colon be used? e.g.:

To be, or not to be: that is the question.

Comment: A colon or a dash both work fine for me—or even better, a question, since a question is after all what it is. A comma is too weak for the pause we all know is there in that phrase. I wouldn’t put a comma in _to be or not to be_, though.

Comment: You should clarify whether you are talking about how best to punctuate the line _as a standalone sentence of Modern English_, or whether you are looking for Shakespeare’s own punctuation. That makes rather a big difference in this case.

Comment: "2BR02B?"  (and thanks for all the fish)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft 2B|~2B From one StackOverflower to another.

Answer (score 4):

The only two texts with any authority, Q2 and F1, point this differently:

> Q2: To be, or not to be, that is the question,
>
> F1: To be, or not to be, that is the Question:

The relative authority of Q2 and F1 has been hotly debated for centuries, mostly with respect to the fairly long passages unique to each. It is impossible to know whose pointing and orthography either represents: Shakespeare's, a copyist's, Heminges and Condell's, or the printers'.

But the important thing to keep in mind is that the pointing is irrelevant. *Hamlet* was composed not as a text for reading but as a text for playing, and each individual actor chooses how the text will be phrased and delivered, without regard to the feeble devices of literary editors.

Comment: *Hamlet* is a masterwork of the English canon; we quote from it constantly. How it is punctuated is more important than what marks S, Q2, or F1 used.

That said, when the question asks for a definitive answer to the issue, we ultimately have to fall back on the earliest and most authoritative texts... even though they were (badly) punctuated with a mind towards their being read aloud in the diction of the times.

Answer (score 2):

To be or not to be? That is the question.

Comment: -1. This is not a matter of opinion. It is a quote, and of a well known work. You need a source on this.

Comment: @Susan, I disagree with that. I realise now that it is not quite clear from the question itself, but I understood it as being a question not of what the original spelling and punctuation was, but what is (in Modern English) the best way to clearly punctuate a line that just happens to be a famous quote.

Comment: @Susan Care to respond to the objection?

Comment: @d'alar'cop - trust me, I comment when I care.

Comment: Yeah, I initially downvoted this since StoneyB has the weight of tradition on his side but the question was "how *should* it be punctuated" with an eye towards finding the proper modern sense in it.

In a quote, we should mostly use the quarto and folio versions but they were written with an eye towards stage diction and followed different standards from modern punctuation. This is a valid answer to what it should look like in a modern work.

Answer (score 0):

*The Norton Shakespeare*, p. 1705, ed. Stephen Greenblatt, (1997: W.W. Norton & Company, Inc.) writes it this way:

'To be, or not to be; that is the question:'

The colon after 'question' only makes sense if you are continuing the passage. If not, then I would end with a full stop after 'question'.

Comment: Thanks for that but this is the internet. You can find the original quartos and folios if you poke around. *Norton* may be what the English prof is cribbing out of but it's not any more authoritative than d'alar'cop when it differs from the original texts. They used a comma; if we're dropping that, question marks and colons both work much better than Greenblatt's semicolon.

Comment: Further, if you don't continue the passage, you end with an ellipsis, not a period.

Answer (score -2):

Because the sentence goes on -*whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer...*, there has to be either a semicolon or a colon after *question*, depending on whether you think Hamlet is amplifying his point or merely explaining it. That means there can be neither colon nor semicolon after *be*, but only a comma.

Even if there were a full stop after *question*, I would still vote for the comma - would you really write "The question is; to be or not to be?" - but it would be more a matter of opinion.